# jekyll find filename portion of page url

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I need to extract the filename portion of the page url, that is from a post saved in `2011-12-31-new-years-eve-is-awesome.md` I would like to just the part `new-years-eve-is-awesome` .

Unfortunately `post_url` contains also the directory tree `2011/12/31/`

This page https://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/ seems to suggest that defining

```
---
shorttitle: :title
---
```

in the front matter should work but that produces an empty string from `{{ post.shorttitle }}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution so far. Perhaps there is a variable left in the code but it's not documented, therefore I just filter the post URL:

```
{% assign spliturl = post.url | split: '/' %}
{% assign postname = spliturl[4] | replace: '.html', '' %}

{{ postname }}
```